# OpenCV phaseCorrelate usage

Tags: c++, opencv

I am processing binary images with OpenCV, that have very different phase angles which I try to detect with phaseCorrelate.
My code works, but the result is disappointing: I receive some value for the x-axis, and for y-axis a very small, hardly > 0 (e.g.2,5E-15), so I do round them to integers which results in e.g. -365 / 0, which I use to shift and flip my binary.
my code looks like this:

```
Mat reference; // is of some size and type CV_8U,
Mat workImage; // dito
...
cv::Point2d cr = phaseCorrelate( Mat_<float>( reference ), Mat_<float>( workImage ) );
Mat correctedMat = ShiftAndFlipImage(workImage, cr);
```

The result of my method `ShiftAndFlipImage` equals the image I receive with
*GIMP: Layer-Transform-Offset (Ctrl+Shift+O)*, so there's no doubt.
Only question I have is about the result of `phaseCorrelate`.
I also tried this hanning-Window approach, but no advance.

Can anyone give recommendations on this?
The resulting image does not really match the reference,

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, I just had to switch the arguments, resulting in a sign change. mea culpa 8-|
(Additionally, I will ask the real question I have about this in a new post)

Comment: can you share the link to the new post?